# Framework directory on my xcode project is missing

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I created a xcode project in the usual way (Create a new Xcode Project -> Single View -> Obj c for iphones -> create). and the framework directory is missing.

Also when I try to "Link Binary with Libraries" the frameworks and libraries are empty. While trying to include a SDK ('AppLovin') the file shows up in the project but it is not recognized as a framework or library.

I will be happy if someone will show me how to create a project with a "frameworks" directory. Also if someone will be able to show me how to link this library.

Comment: Are you sure 'AppLovin' is implemented as a dynamic framework and needs to be copied to the app bundle?

Comment: Even though I am almost positively sure that it is a "dynamic framework" but I am not completely sure, how can I check this?

Comment: Have a look at its payload using the `file` command.